# Android 2.3 problem with EditText onKeyListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-sdk-2.3

I have an app made for the 1.6 version, and it works great till 2.2. Now I am making some updates and realize that onKeyListener won't work on 2.3, on previous versions is good. Check this

```
etValue.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

etValue is EditText.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this code on 2.3.1  its working Pls Try it

```
EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
ed.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is the same with this code. But I see that it won't work with soft keyboard, it works good with hardware keyboard. What could be the problem?

Comment: Yes u r right But when u press Enter key on softkeyboard then it works& Toast is Display

Comment: Yes, but it is not the same behavior from the previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using EditText in a dialog and you implement onShowListener on the dialog?
This may have caused dialog to take away focus from the EditText field. Remove onShowListener for dialog. You may instead implement onFocusChanged for the EditText to determine kinda implicitly when the dialog is shown.